# Cucumber and lambda step defenition

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried to obtain steps of a feature. When i run the feature file it gives me
something like

```
Given("^I want to register into the main forum$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
```

which is a lambda function.

I used to see it as class like below

```
Class StepDefinition{

    @Given("^I want to register into the main forum$")
    public void given(){

    }
}
```

**but i am wondering how i can use this lambda?**

Comment: You right the code to login into main forum by prviding username password and clicking login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
public void given(){
       Given("^I want to register into the main forum$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
      });
}
```

and then setup the java version of STS to `java8`